# Google Cloud Build substitutions to Google Cloud Run env vars

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have the following `cloudbuild.yaml` file, and I'm trying to inject ebvariables from substitutions (I'll be re-using a Cloud Build trigger across multiple services, so I'd like to configure it to the hilt).

I'm currently doing something similar to this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
    id: 'Build & Push Image'
    args:
      - '--destination=us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME:$SHORT_SHA'
      - '--destination=us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME:latest'
      - '--dockerfile=Dockerfile'
      - '--context=.'
      - '--cache=true'
      - '--cache-ttl=120h'

  - id: 'Deploy to Cloud Run'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud run deploy $_SERVICE_NAME \
        --image=us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE_NAME:$SHORT_SHA \
        --region=$_REGION --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated \
        --port=8983
    env:
      - 'API_VERSION_LATEST="v1"'
      - 'ASCOM_ALPACA_API_DEVICE_ID=$_DEVICE_ID'
      - 'ASCOM_ALPACA_API_BASE_URL=$_BASE_URL'
      - 'ASCOM_ALPACA_API_IP_ADDRESS=$_IP_ADDRESS'
      - 'PLEIADES_API_KEY=$_API_KEY'
      - 'TAILSCALE_HOST_NAME=$_TAILSCALE_HOST_NAME'
      - 'TAILSCALE_EPHEMERAL_AUTH_KEY=$_TAILSCALE_EPHEMERAL_AUTH_KEY'

substitutions:
  _IMAGE_NAME: ???
  _SERVICE_NAME: ???
  _REGION: uscentral-1

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

But the environment variable passing doesn't seem to be working. I was wondering ... what is the correct method for passing env vars from substitutions to the `gcloud run` command? Does anyone have any examples, or a documentation reference (I can't seem to get anything that I feel confident is correct).

Comment: update your answer with how do you pass substitutions? why is it `gcloud run`? if you submit a build from a console it should be `gcloud builds submit --substitutions=....`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm using the continuous integration approach if that helps...

Comment: Your `cloudbuild.yaml` looks OK to me and your [user-defined substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) look good. You state without any evidence that the "environment variable passing doesn't work". Please include logs or other output that supports this statement.

Comment: Essentially the Tailscale VPN isn't being setup with the variables I am passing. The setup fails -> and the host and ephemeral key both aren't set correctly.

Comment: I'm setting the _TAILSCALE_HOST_NAME substation when I trigger the build, to say "HELLOWORLD" and then in my Tailscale dashboard I am seeing "localhost" which is incorrect.

Comment: So everything is suggesting that the environment is not correctly setup.

Comment: Effectively, I want to be able to set the environment INSIDE each cloud run container ... it's crazy that this is so hard to reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `env` section in cloudbuild.yaml sets environment variables for the Cloud Build VM that runs gcloud, not for the Cloud Run containers. You need to pass the `--set-env-vars` flag to `gcloud run deploy` if you want Cloud Run to see them.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much for your reply. So effectively, I could drop the env section of the build ... and then just utilise something like `--set-env-vars "ASCOM_ALPACA_API_DEVICE_ID=$_DEVICE_ID" \` in the gcloud run deploy command? :)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: is there a way to update the existing ones without deleting the previously set? i am using cloud run and set up the env vars in cloud run config.